# Kotlin: how to return running service instance in binder?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have working **Java** code for `Service` and trying to convert it to **Kotlin**.

```
class MyService : Service() {

    companion object MyBinder : Binder() {
        fun getService() : MyService? {
            return MyService::class.objectInstance
        }
    }

    // service implementation

}
```

The problem is that in activities `getService()` always returns null. I am sure the `service` is started before, I see it in logcat. I suggest this auto generated line from Java code should be different but I cannot find the solution:

```
return MyService::class.objectInstance
```

In Java code it is:

```
return MyService.this
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Below code will help your

```
class MyService : Service() {

    inner class MyBinder : Binder() {
        fun getService() : MyService? {
            return this@MyService
        }
    }

    // service implementation

}
```

More info regarding this expression in Kotlin 
[This Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html)

Comment: Yeah, this is the right solution, it works now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is the short way doing it (including additionally onBind())

```
class MyService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent) = LocalBinder()

    inner class LocalBinder : Binder() {
        fun getService() = this@SensorService
    }
}
```